# Android Is it posible to get an Activity's preference value from a Service?

Tags: android, service, android-preferences

Given that a Service may be running even when the launching activity is destroyed,
and also that data is passed usually using the extra bundle along the intent,
I wonder if the Service is able to **directly access the activity's preferences**.

My guess is *no, it cannot*. But it would save me writing a chunk of code if it can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that You're asking about [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). If so, then documentation is clear (by link above):

> Note: currently this class does not support use across multiple
> processes. This will be added later.

So, currently, if Your service is running in a separate process it's not possible. In that case I would suggest to store Your preferences not in a SharedPreferences, but in some base which could be accessible via specific ContentProvider.

P.S. Actually I tried access SharedPreferences from multiple processes and it has worked (at least in my case), but I've decided to use another way because of the documentation mentioned in the answer.

Comment: My Service runs in the same process as the UI, so I infer from your answer that the default SharedPreferences are available inside the service, right? ::: Should I pass the activity context or the service context is good for getDefaultSharedPreferences(context) ?

Comment: I would suggest not to pass Activity context to SharedPreferences. Actually, Application Context will be enough. Moreover, looks like (based on android source), ContextImpl has single static instance of SharedPreferences and ContextWrappers (like activities) are just accessing it. If You curious, checkout http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#ContextImpl and http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/content/ContextWrapper.java .

Answer (score 0):

If you mean [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences) then you can just call getSharedPreferences with the same name.